# How does iOS encrypt and decrypt binaries?

Tags: iphone, ios, security, encryption, cryptography

I am an iOS developer and was wondering if anyone has insight as to how binary encryption works in iOS? I.e. does Apple sign the app using it's private key to distribute on the app store and then decrypts it with the corresponding public-key when loading the application? Or is it something other than public/private key encryption?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you already read [Apple’s *iOS Security*](http://images.apple.com/ipad/business/docs/iOS_Security_May12.pdf)?

Answer (score 3):

Apple's DRM system for apps, as well as for Music, etc, is called **FairPlay**.

You can find a lot of infos about this on the net.
Mainly:

- [FairPlay - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FairPlay)
- [How FairPlay Works: Apple's iTunes DRM Dilemma](http://www.roughlydrafted.com/RD/RDM.Tech.Q1.07/2A351C60-A4E5-4764-A083-FF8610E66A46.html)

Comment: +1 for some interesting links even though the question might be off topic.